# Cross-platform unique identifier for a computer

Tags: license-key

I am writing a commercial application which will have license keys which will be checked and validated server side. I would like to restrict the amount of computers that the application can be installed on (ie 1 copy only). IP addresses can be unreliable for this scenario. Is there any unique identifier between computers on all operating systems?

Comment: Perhaps, can this be easily changed by a user?

Comment: Easliy not, but it can be changed. However, most of the "unique" things can be changed in computation (at least in software).  You can make a mix with other hashes including the MAC to make more bulletproof

Comment: Good idea - would you mind adding it as an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read MAC address or UUID to make more bulletproof, and identify the computer by the mix of both.

If you can read the UUID maybe it's enough to identify unique computer even in different operating systems.

Since you don't tag with a language this question, there are several possible ways to read that values.

Comment: Do MAC addresses not transfer between operating systems?

Comment: Theorically yes, it's a hardware identifier, but it can be changed with software, so it's the software in the end point who returns the final value. Hardware MAC can be "XXX", and the software can return "YYY".

Comment: I assume both of these can be accessed via Python?

Comment: Probably best for me to ask that in a separate question - in fact I will do that shortly.

Comment: Yeah, I will show you some links: https://www.google.es/search?q=python+read+UUID || https://www.google.es/search?q=python+read+MAC But take care, don't get it from server, get it from client (assuming you are getting the value from client and then send it to server)

Comment: Yes, I will be getting the value from the client, convert it to a hash and send it to the server (or something like that). Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck with the commercialization of the software. The hardest task :)